# automatically activate whenever there is http://www... between div tags

Tags: html, css, hyperlink

I searched stackoverflow , similar question doesn't exist.

Just wanted to know if there was any short html shortcut to activate hyperlinks whenever there is `http://www.` between div tags. thanks for info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. HTML provides no methods to search an element for text that looks like it might be a URL and turn it into a link.

There are, however, [numerous questions about using *programming languages* to modify documents in a similar fashion](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+automatically+hyperlink+urls&oq=site%3Astackoverflow.com+automatically+hyperlink+urls&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i58.11079j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8).

Answer (score 0):

try this code that detects url in text

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6u5eM/1/

```
function findUrls( text ) //the text you want to search a url for
{
    var source = (text || '').toString();
    var urlArray = [];
    var url;
    var matchArray;

    // Regular expression to find FTP, HTTP(S) and email URLs.
    var regexToken = /(((ftp|https?):\/\/)[\-\w@:%_\+.~#?,&\/\/=]+)|((mailto:)?[_.\w-]+@([\w][\w\-]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,3})/g;

    // Iterate through any URLs in the text.
    while( (matchArray = regexToken.exec( source )) !== null )
    {
        var token = matchArray[0];
        urlArray.push( token );
    }

    return urlArray;
}
alert( findUrls( 'http://www.site.com fejisojfiosf fsehiofes ' ) ); //returns url from text
```